# What's the meaning of "turn over" in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, interpretation

> May a new year turn over a new leaf, and try a new way forward.

Source: JoongAng Daily

I searched up the meaning of "turn over" in the Merriam-Webster dictionary

> 1 a : to turn from an upright position : overturn b : rotate ; also : to cause (an internal
>   combustion engine) to begin firing
>   2 : to search (as clothes or
>   papers) by lifting or moving one by one
>   3 : to read or examine (as a
>   book) slowly or idly
>   4 : deliver, surrender ;  also : to lose possession of 
>   5 a : to receive and dispose of (a stock of merchandise)  b :
>   to do business to the amount of

Which meaning of 'turn over' is used in the sentence I quoted?

I guess it is 4(lose possession of).

Is my guess correct?

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turn%20over, click on "v" button to show more info. `turn over a new leaf:  to make a change for the better especially in one's way of living`

Comment: This is actually an idiom. You need to search the full idiom, "turn over a new leaf."

Comment: @AlexK Thank you for your help. May I delete my question or should I just leave it?

Comment: Your question has received two votes, I would leave it.

Comment: Also relevant, I think the "leaf" in the idiom is refering to a "leaf" of paper, which is a sheet of paper inside a book.

Comment: It's not a particularly "natural" usage, in that no-one would be likely to say *May next Friday turn over a new leaf*. It's really just a (clumsy, imho) allusion to the tradition of making a New Year's Resolution that one will *radically change one's behaviour for the better* (turn over a new leaf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "turn over a new leaf" is to make a fresh start or an improvement.